# Function send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am wondering about how i can to check if the email has been correctly sent before I redirect to another page. Because if it's not fast it will redirect before the request has been finished ..

```
while (reader.Read())
{


    Fct.SendEmail("test.test.com", "test.test.com", "Maxime", userEmail, "email@myemail.com", "Access to our portal / Your password", body);



}

Response.Redirect("Logon.aspx");
```

and this is my function send email :

```
 public void SendEmail(string smtpServer, string mailFrom, string mailFromDisplayName, string mailTo, string mailCc, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer))
            {
                string to = mailTo != null ? string.Join(",", mailTo) : null;
                string cc = mailCc != null ? string.Join(",", mailCc) : null;

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, mailFromDisplayName);
                mail.To.Add(to);

                if (cc != null)
                {
                    mail.Bcc.Add(cc);
                }

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<BR>");
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                client.Send(mail);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        { ex.ToString(); }
    }
```

Comment: What is this `Fct` class/object?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear, and your code doesn't really seem to be the important code we need to see.

Comment: I would get rid of that `try..catch` thing or at least do _not_ ignore the result of `ex.ToString();`, including the [`InnerException` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# MailMessage class - How to verify server carried out the message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914660/c-sharp-mailmessage-class-how-to-verify-server-carried-out-the-message) (and many more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mails get put into a queue prior to despatch - usually it's in c:\inetpub\mailroot\

When the poller picks up the message, it places it into the badmail folder if the mail send fails - so check this folder for failures.

The client.Send(msg) will only error if it can't create the message - it doesn't error for bad email addresses or any other error once it's created the email for the SMTP server to process.